# What determines revive time?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have noticed the more times I die in a game, the longer I must wait to revive.  What is the formula for revive time and is there a cap?

Comment: The answer was "I don't know"

Comment: Just because it has a bad answer doesn't mean you should ask again.  Ask the answerer to improve his answer or post a bounty.

Comment: We should probably call it the revive timer because the game calls it that, and searching for revive under diablo-3 turns up nothing...

Comment: @Pent good call

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know the exact formula, but the delay seems to increase by 5 seconds each time you die.  It starts at 3 seconds and has a max of 28.

It does not seem to be affected by any other actions, and resets after 2 minutes.

Comment: Excessive amount of time = 2 minutes :)

Comment: I recall being able to die around 3 times before the timer goes beyond 3 seconds.

Comment: @SadlyNot I also seem to remember that occurring, but I could not reproduce it in my tests.  If anyone can offer evidence of this, I will update my answer.

Comment: Just verified, was at 30 sec timer and went back to town for 2min. Came back and at 3sec timer.

Answer (score 2):

The approximate formula is that every time you die within 2 minutes, 5 seconds is added to the revive timer.  If you don't die within 2 minutes the timer resets and you can once again revive in 3 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

As of patch 1.0.7, there is not such thing a death penalty:

> The resurrection timer will no longer increase if a player is killed multiple times in a row

[Source](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/8608455/patch-107-now-live-2-12-2013#general)

Answer (score 1):

The respawn timer when you die keeps increasing , if you wait 2 min it will go back to zero