# When does the revive timer resets?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What determines respawn time?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68593/what-determines-respawn-time)

Every time I die, the revive timer grows. When does it reset?

At inferno difficulty I die quite a lot