# What determines how fast I can revive?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What determines respawn time?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68593/what-determines-respawn-time)

Sometimes I can revive in 3 seconds, sometimes 12, sometimes even more, is there a table that governs these delays? And what are these changes based on, solely how frequently I die?